# blowing or puffing? To release air out of mouth

Tags: clauses

When we cool the hot food by releasing air out of mouth, do we say:

> Blow over the food to cool it.

OR

> Puff over the food to cool it.

Actually in 'blowing' it seems to be as if there is a lot of force that will move the food far away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We blow **on** hot food to *cool it down*.